# can't sen $_POST via $.ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to put my site on the internet but I have faced a problem with ajax so I tried to create a simple function to test it:
This is my jQuery function:

```
function test(){
    $.ajax({
        async:true,
        type:"POST",
        url:"controller/test.php",
        data:"order=testingConnectionToServer",
        success:function(result){
                alert(result);
        },
        error:function(xhr,msgError){
            alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
            alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
        }
    }); 

}
```

I call this function when page is loaded.
And this is my php code in `test.php`:

```
<?php
echo 'test ok: $_POST[\'order\'] = '.$_POST['order'];
?>
```

But this is the result I get:
[image]

**Note** that this function is working good on localhost but when I put it on the internet it doesn't work!!
This is what the console shows me:
[image]

Comment: maybe to try write data in json format  - data: { order : "testingConnectionToServer" } ?

Comment: At this point I can only assume that the request data isn't being sent. Can we get a link to the issue?

Comment: I have edited my question please check it out.

Comment: There's an error within your php code

Comment: Is that everything in your test.php file?

Comment: @Anonymous yes it's just a simple file to test the ajax function

Comment: Did you try adding `contentType: 'text/plain'` to the $.ajax request?

Comment: `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` is preffered

Comment: @vp_arth your soution worked like charm thnx :), but what is the explanation of that ?

Comment: php didn't know about format of incoming data

Comment: it's some strange, because it's default value for `contentType` :)

Comment: why you are rendering javascript alert using php .. I can't understand what you are trying to do ..

Comment: @JijoJohn, where? I see simple echo script...

Comment: yeah beacause it's the first time I face this problem but thnx again :)

Comment: @Slimen If you are inclined to do so, you could view the request headers and compare them with and without the `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`.  In IE, press F12 and, on the Network tab, press the Play button before the request is made by the JavaScript.  Double-clicking on the POST method line will give you a detailed summary of what request headers are generated by the code.

Comment: @apandit I will try it thnx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you have some `$.ajaxSetup` call, which overrides default value of `contentType` key.

Pass correct `contentType` to your `$.ajax` call.

It's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for `var=1&var2=2` data format.

Comment: Thnx for the explanation :)

Comment: There's an option called `global` in `$.ajax` which accepts `bool` to consider `global` ajax setup or not and by default it's `true` which says to accept global setups.. Just an info..

Answer (score 0):

You need to put braces {} inside the data object.Here's the updated code. i think this one will work for you. If you return json or any other interchanging format you need to define a dataType.

```
function test(){
$.ajax({
    async:true,
    type:"POST",
    dataType : 'json',
    url:"controller/test.php",
    data:{order : 'Your text'},
    success:function(result){
            alert(result);
    },
    error:function(xhr,msgError){
        alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

 }
```

Comment: We can send data in the way OP has used too.